# Credit card expired and no replacement sent

Tags: credit-card

My credit card expired in January 2019. I did not receive a new card.

I contacted the company on 2/1/2019 was told they had to do a report and I would receive a new card in 7 to 10 days.

On 2/18/2019 I contacted the company again and was told they had to cancel card that was issued on 2/1/2019, and I would receive a card in 7 to 10 days.

On 3/1/2019 I contacted the company again and was told they would have to reissue the card before they got to the 7 to 10 days. I requested the card to be sent FedEx to my home address (I receive regular mail at a PO box). They told me I would receive the card in 3 to 5 days.

On the 6th I contacted the company again. This time I was told it hadn't been sent out because of the address update. This is the same physical address I had when applying for card. I was told the supervisor would contact me on Friday or Monday to update me as to it being sent.

As of today (Tuesday) I've heard nothing. Do I have any options?

Comment: I'm sorry you've had such a lot of trouble with it. Before this question is answerable here it needs some significant clean up... could you comment or edit the question to explain where you live (which jurisdiction) and also to more clearly state the question? At the moment it reads a bit like a stream of consciousness and it's hard to understand.

Comment: Make sure there hasn’t been any activity on your account while you haven’t had the card. Stealing new cards out of the mail is not unheard of.

Answer (score 7):

The credit card company you are doing business with is clearly doing a poor job. Why are you continuing to do business with them? Get a credit card with a company that is responsive to your needs, and close your account with the company that is unresponsive.